docker-compose not setting psql user or db
I have a project with only this compose.yml
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db

But when I use table plus or pgadmin4 to view I get an error about the user user. I can connect with pgadmin using postgres as the user though. So it looks like it only creates a postgres user and the default postgres db?
I'm getting this error
connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist

This exact file was creating user and test_db a week ago. So I'm not sure what has changed. It's the only file in the project aside from a nuke shell command
#!/bin/bash

# Stop and remove all containers
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)

# Remove all volumes
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)

# Remove all images
docker rmi $(docker images -aq)

this makes sure there are no volumes, images, or containers
am I missing something? Shouldn't
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db

create the user and test_db?
========
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
632d2de6ce44   postgres:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   46 seconds ago   Exited (0) 2 seconds ago             postgresql


I have the same setup in an actual web project and I can connect to the db using the "user" and "test_db" parameters for my db config, which is also confusing me. But in that project I also cannot view the db from table plus or pgadmin but can see the postgres user and postgres db are made

"when I use table plus or pgadmin4 to view" Are you doing that on localhost:5432?  "I have the same setup in an actual web project" ... - "5432:5432" ... " you can have this port mapping in exactly one of your running docker compose files at once.  My theory, is that you have "actual web project" running, and since 5432 is bound to that, you're not actually connecting to the postgresql container you think you are.

My config for the table viewer is
host: 127.0.0.1 (which the docker container shows as local host and this seems fine)
user: user
password: password
port: 5432
in the full web app my backend is at port 3000 and can connect to the db with the above config. and the frontend is at port 8000.

check docker ps  & docker ps -afirst,see if there is any pg container running, stop any container that is running using docker stop <container id> , if you want to remove everything before you want to build the image do docker system prune -a , this happens if you have some pg dangling containers, even if its not running

pruning did clear out a bunch of old default containers and such but still not working :/
getting the "connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist"

wait i am testing it

yeah, because it's a different postgres server than you think.  I can pretty much guarantee you you have some other postgres, either dockerized or nondockerized, listening to localhost:5432 with a different user configuration.  You're clearly connecting to something.

I've done a full computer reset, no other terminals or apps running. Nuked and pruned docker. I don't seem to have anything else running at port 5432. I can see the logs on the db and when I do interactions with the web app, it does show up there. But I just cant view the db with a table viewer.

`    ~/Desktop/test/pg-container  docker exec -it 3238192024bc bash                                                        ✔
root@3238192024bc:/# psql -U user -d test_db
psql (16.4 (Debian 16.4-1.pgdg120+1))
Type "help" for help.
test_db=#`
i could create and connect to the db

so the compose psql environment section created a "user" and a "test_db"? huh. I'm not sure what else I am missing here. I can connect to the db with user: postgres and there is a database named "postgres" in there

ah its  just that your machine 5432 port is used , just do another port bind
-ports:      5433:5432 and rebuild the container , test if that works

can you show me the ouput of docker ps -a just do this and update in the question

I did try updating the ports to something completely different -- ports: - "8001:8001" -- and when I run docker compose up in there, it still builds it at port 5432... so it seems like it isn't reading everything in my compose file?

why would you change to 8001:8001 just do 5433:5432  default port of pg is 5432 that should be mapped from inside the container to open port in host i.e your machine. why would you do more than asked

I did a prune again and it looks like changing the port to 5433:5432 did it. I'm able to connect there now . Not sure I fully understand that one. Thank you @nabinsademba

hahaha I wanted to see what would happen and if it was picking up the port number at all

just do what is asked :) , you need to understand that your port 5432 in your machine is occupied by some other service, you ran docker system prune -a  this commands only deletes stopped containers and other resources to stopped container . i am sure there is a running container occupying 5432 in your machine. you need to run docker ps and stop it using docker stop <container id>, and run prune again and rebuild your container as originally you used to do. but make sure to stop all the container before you run prune and then rebuild

i think i resolved your issue in the comment should i answer :P  @yankeedoodle

As the answer was resolved in the comment section i just want to explain what was the OP's issue:
default port 5432 for postgres in host machine was occupied by some other service, pobably another running container
for verification:
The diffrent host port was bind done with pg container default port
i.e 5433:5432
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgresql
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db

Therfore service started running as expected, so it was concluded the host port 5432 was occupied.
what to take from here:

always try to bind your host port to any other open port in your
machine  if you default port bind dont work for verification when you face similar issue

